# Implementing IDisposable correctly on parent classes in C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, idisposable

I have a class which implements the C# `SerialPort` which used to look like this:

```
public class AsyncSerial : IDisposable
{
    SerialPort newPort; //Parameters declared in my constructor
    //Constructor and other methods

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if(disposing)
        {
            this.Close();
            this.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

This throws up no warnings in code analysis (I got the code from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182269.aspx) as an example of how to do it properly).

Since I was only ever going to declare one `SerialPort` I figured I would make my class a child of `SerialPort`, but now I get warnings that I can't seem to fix.

```
public class AsyncSerial : SerialPort
{
    //Constructor and other methods

    public new void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected new virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if(disposing)
        {
            this.Close();
            this.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Code warnings said the dispose methods should be `new` as they hide members, which I did, but I also get:

> "Warning  CA1063  Ensure that 'AsyncSerial.Dispose()' is declared as public and sealed"

Making it sealed means it has to be marked `override` (or I get compiler errors), making it override means it can be new, so I end up with:

> Error CS0506 'AsyncSerial.Dispose()': cannot override inherited member 'Component.Dispose()' because it is not marked virtual, abstract, or override

I don't know the 'correct' way to implement disposing on a class with `IDisposable` in the parent class. Every example I find only fits having `IDisposable` as a base, but making my class

```
public class AsyncSerial : SerialPort, IDisposable
{
    //code
}
```

gives me a code analysis warning because `SerialPort` already implements `IDisposable`.

Should I just suppress the warning about Ensuring that 'AsyncSerial.Dispose()' is declared as public and sealed, or is there a correct way to do this which doesn't give code analysis warning.

Comment: Embedding SerialPort is fine but you only need to dispose it in your Dispose() method, nothing else and no need for the disposable pattern.  Never hesitate to use *sealed*.  Inheriting is fine too, but then you need to *only* override Dispose(bool) and not inherit IDisposable.  Since you don't seem to have anything else disposable that isn't necessary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your subclass should override `Dispose(bool disposing)` if anything - that's the whole point of having that method at all, really.

However, I suspect that the base class will make the right calls anyway, so you shouldn't need to do anything, unless you have extra resources to release which *aren't* released in `Close()`. If that's the case, do that in `Dispose(bool disposing)`:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    // Allow the base class to release resources
    base.Dispose(disposing);
    // Release any extra resources here 
}
```

Note that your current implementation will lead to a StackOverflowException as your two `Dispose` overloads call each other.

Comment: Ok, I will make sure I dispose anything I create in the child class (although I don't think there is anything). The base class dispose everything else, I was overcomplicating it and confusing myself.
Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

The Dispose Pattern was designed to allow derived types to add disposal logic in consistent fashion without regard for whether the parent type has a public `Dispose` method or implements `IDisposable.Dispose` explicitly.  Types which derive from a type that follows the pattern should simply override `Dispose(bool)` regardless of how the parent class implements uses a public method or explicit implementation for `IDisposable.Dispose()`.

Although the design of the `Dispose` pattern was based on the flawed assumption that publicly-exposed objects of inheritable types will often need to incorporate finalizers directly (rather than encapsulating unmanaged resources in privately-held instances of private types whose purpose is to clean up those resources), compiler-generated cleanup logic in C++/CLI (and maybe other languages as well) relies upon the pattern and so it's a good idea to use it with inheritable classes which may be used by other people.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to declare a `public void Dispose()` method on the child class, because it was already inherited from the base one (The compiler won't let you anyways, unless you hide the base implementation with the `new` keyword).

You also don't need to override the base class's `protected virtual void Dispose(bool)` if you're not going to dispose anything specific to this child class.

If you were to have an `IDisposable` reference in your child class, then you should **override** your base class's method:

```
public class AsyncSerial : SerialPort, IDisposable
{
    // SomeClass implements IDisposable
    private SomeClass _disposableInstance;

    // ...

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if(disposing)
        {
            if(_disposableInstance != null)
                _disposableInstance.Dispose();
        }

        // Call the base Dispose, to release resources on the base class.
        base.Dipose(disposing);
    }
}
```